# Spring Itegration Example

Tags: spring

Can someone post Spring Integration example codes for [Messaging Patterns / Message Routing / Routing Slip](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/RoutingTable.html) ?

Comment: No! No! No! ...

Answer (score 0):

Check https://github.com/adambarnes5000/routing-slips for using Spring Integration's routing slip functionality